# Maintain order of saved attributes list for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes, rubygems, acts-as-list

I have two models with a has_many to has_many relationship through a join table.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorings, -> { order(:position) }, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :authors, through: :authorings
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorings, -> { order(:position) }
    has_many :articles, through: :authorings
end

class Authoring < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :article
  acts_as_list :scope => :author
end
```

The getter and setter methods for the array

```
def author_list
    self.authors.collect do |author|
        author.name
    end.join(', ')
end

def author_list=(author_array)
    author_names = author_array.collect { |i| 
        i.strip.split.each do |j|
            j.capitalize
        end.join(' ') }.uniq
    new_or_found_authors = author_names.collect { |name| Author.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
    self.authors = new_or_found_authors
end
```

I want to maintain the order of the list of authors that get saved to the model. That is, I would like to be able to change and reorder the author_list and have it retrieved in that order for the view. I want to be to change it ['foo','bar'] or ['bar','foo']. How can I do this?

As a note, I have tried using acts_as_list and added a position column to the database for authoring but to no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a position attribute for each author.

Then you can generate a sorted activerecord array and grab the name attribute

```
authorlist = Author.order(:position).pluck(:name)
```

I'm not seeing how you're changing the position attribute, I'm guessing you need some sort of js on the frontend to do that.